# how to create expression onfly

Tags: c#, linq

I have a sample query class which contains query parameters as its' properties. this class is used for WCF communication and on the server-side appropriate filter expression is generated.

where is sample code.

```
internal interface IExpressionBuilder<T>
{
   Func<T, bool> Build();
}
```

here is sample implementation

```
[DataContract]
public class PersonQuery : IExpressionBuilder<Person>
{
    [DataMember]
    public string IdCardNumber;
    [DataMember]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public DateTime? BirthDate { get; set; }

    #region Implementation of IExpressionBuilder<Data>

    public Func<Person, bool> Build()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

usage:

```
publi List<Person> GetPersonByQuery(PersonQuery query)
{
    (using context = new SampleContext())
    {
        return List<Person> foundPersons = context.people.where(query.build());
    }
}
```

u can see that idea is very sample but my question is how to dynamically include PersonQuery properties in expression if they are set, when build() method is called, based on

Comment: Hi, can you correct your code sample, it won't work: `using` parenthesis, `return List<Person> foundPersons =`, and `.where()` won't work because it returned `IQueryable<T>`, not a `List<T>`, unless, you `.ToList()` it.

Comment: It looks like your `IExpressionBuilder<T>.Build` method should return an `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` otherwise your query will fetch all records from the `people` table and filter them on the client.

Comment: Actually I return it tolist() i just forgot to include that code here.

Lee Expression<Func<T, bool>> I know at the very begining this was the signature of the method my problem is how to build that expression inside build method? based on properties? if Firstname is set I want to include it inside filter query and same for all other properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at [Dynamic Linq](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx)? It seems ideally suited to your problem.

If you want to use functions and build expression trees, [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mitsu/archive/2010/03/02/c-4-expressions-blocks-part-i.aspx) library provides a nice, fluent syntax for creating expression trees.

Comment: ok this is very interesting post, but could u provide sample implementation of my build method? I iUsed PredicaeBuilder from this link
http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx

this is how I build query
var personExpression = PredicateExtensions.True<Person>();

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(IdCardNumber))
   personExpression.And(p => p.IdCardNumber == IdCardNumber);
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(FirstName))
    personExpression.And(p => p.FirstName == FirstName);

but insted of adding where criteria to ma queries entity framework profiler shows only full select